# Output of Build.Repository.Name from a powershell script running in data external of Terraform

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, terraform

I need to fetch the Azure DevOps Repository Name (output of Build.Repository.Name) from a powershell script that is running in Terraform external data source in Terraform script. But I am getting blank output. Below is the script to refer. Am I calling the system build variable correctly in powershell? Kindly check and help here.

Terraform main.tf

```
    data "external" "repo" {
  program = ["pwsh", "${abspath(path.module)}/fetch_repo_name.ps1"]
  query = {
    always = timestamp()
  }
}
```

Powershell Script

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
$jsonpayload = [Console]::In.ReadLine()
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonpayload

$always = $json.always

$outputJson = @{RepoName = $($env:BUILD_Repository_Name);} | ConvertTo-Json

    Write-Output $outputJson
```

Output

```
Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + repo-name = [
      + (known after apply),
    ]
data.external.repo: Reading...
data.external.repo: Read complete after 1s [id=-]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

repo-name = [
  tomap({
    "RepoName" = ""
  }),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code. I was using wrong way of referring Azure DevOps System variable in PowerShell. It must be all CAPS and dot must be replaced with "_". Also use `$env`.

Corrected PowerShell Script

```
$outputJson = @{RepoName = $($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME);} | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output $outputJson
```

Output

```
Outputs:
    
    repo-name = [
      tomap({
        "RepoName" = "Vnetest_Repo"
      }),
    ]
```